# How to use a Terraform script as a "common" script, a library or subroutine, if you will?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I see [How to share a terraform script without module dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900522/how-to-share-a-terraform-script-without-module-dependencies), but I have a different scenario (though that post was also excellent).

In my case I have a script that creates a spot fleet request. I want to use this a common script to create multiple spot fleet requests.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.17, < 0.13.10"
}

resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "jenkins_build_fleet" {
  ...
  launch_specification {
  ...
  }
}
```

I want one script to have

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-remote-states"
    key    = "jenkins-qa/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

... another to have

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-remote-states"
    key    = "jenkins-slaves/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

IOW, each script only differs in its remote state key, so when I apply/destroy their respective plans, they will create their own spot fleet request without affecting any other spot fleet request. I want to be able to run each concrete script without having to specify a `-target` parameter, implying, that I don't want to have all 3 scripts in the same directory. Ideally, I'd want the file structure to be

```
/path/common_script.tf
/path/script1/script1.tf
/path/script2/script2.tf
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: terraform doesn't support vars in the `backend` configuration. Otherwise, it could be done easily with a common module & tfvars pointing to each env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Terraform Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) for this sort of thing. The S3 backend provider has support for Workspaces, and will create a separate "folder" in S3 to store the state file for each workspace.

I have used this with much success to deploy dev/test/prod environments with the same Terraform files. You just need to run `terraform workspace select` before running `terraform apply`

---

I would also say the concept of a "common" library in Terraform is more along the lines of what [Terraform Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html) solves. While your question is more about how to have multiple instances of Terraform managed resources with multiple state files, which is the problem Workspaces solves.

---

**Edit with additional details:**

You could have a single Terraform template file like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.17, < 0.13.10"
}

resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "jenkins_build_fleet" {
  ...
  launch_specification {
  ...
  }
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-remote-states"
    key    = "jenkins/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Then apply it once like this:

```
terraform workspace select jenkins_qa
terraform apply
```

And apply it again like this:

```
terraform workspace select jenkins_slaves
terraform apply
```

And that would result in two separate sets of resources deployed to AWS, with two separate state files in your S3 bucket, prefixed by the workspace name, without having to resort to any duplicate code at all.

**Alternatively, if you want to keep your current separation of files and folders:**

You could have a Terraform module in a `/common` folder like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.17, < 0.13.10"
}

resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "jenkins_build_fleet" {
  ...
  launch_specification {
  ...
  }
}
```

Then you could have a Terraform template in your `/script1` folder like this:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-remote-states"
    key    = "jenkins-qa/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

module "common" {
  source = "../common"
}
```

And either apply this `/script1` template multiple times with different workspaces, or duplicate it into a separate template pointing to a different state file. If the only difference in the duplicated code is the state file's name then you could definitely eliminate that duplication with the use of workspaces.

You mentioned you thought outputs were a requirement for modules, but they are not. You could however output something like the `spot_bid_status` value from the module, and then output it again from the main template, to get it to print to the screen after an `apply` for example.

Comment: So how does Terraform Workspaces solve the idea of NOT having cloned code? Please update your answer on what the directory tree will look like using workspaces. Thanks!

Comment: Also,  If i understand correctly, modules actually have outputs that other scripts can use. For example, I may have a "VPC" module that creates my VPCs, that other modules can then use. In my case, the "common" code doesn't produce an output. Thanks!

Comment: I pointed out modules because that's what terraform "common libraries" usually are. What I'm saying is that you are trying to apply a "common libraries" concept, but your use case sounds more like a single Terraform configuration that needs to be run twice, with two separate state files. That's not really a "common library" so much as a single infrastructure configuration, described by Terraform templates, that is applied twice to your AWS account. That sounds like exactly what Terraform Workspaces are.

Comment: @ChrisF I've added additional examples to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I needed. I'll probably end up with two separate scripts, differing only in the state files, so no one, including me, will have to remember their names.

Answer (score 0):

> IOW, each script only differs in its remote state key

So what is actually in these two files?

```
/path/script1/script1.tf
/path/script2/script2.tf
```

If all they contain is the backend configuration like you've shown then they're redundant. In Terraform a directory is a 'module' which can be reused, so if you wanted to then you could place your 'common script' in a module, but I wouldn't recommend it for this simple case.

Regardless, to answer your question, you can use [partial backend configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#partial-configuration) to support multiple backends. Just pass `-backend-config <backend-config-file>` to your `terraform init` command. For setting up the backend config file see [these docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#backend-configuration-file).

Comment: Because cloning is ALWAYS bad! And this is what I have now. If I need to make a change, I'd have to do it in 2 places. Though I like the `--backend-config` trick, this means I, and other users, will have to remember the name of the config file, and can easily type the wrong one.